# Make a copy of a class made in an if statement accessible outside that statement (Java)

Tags: java

First, sorry if I'm not using the right words about making a copy of a class, I'm new to Java.

```
System.out.println("Choose a class:\nWarrior\nRouge\nCleric\nWizard\nArcher");
    String playerClass = input.nextLine();
    if (playerClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Warrior")){
        playerClass = "warrior";
        Character player = new Warrior();
    }
    if (playerClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Rouge")){
        playerClass = "rouge";
        Character player = new Rouge();
    }
    if (playerClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Cleric")){
        playerClass = "cleric";
        Character player = new Cleric();
    }
    if (playerClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Wizard")){
        playerClass = "wizard";
        Character player = new Wizard();
    }
    if (playerClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Archer")){
        playerClass = "archer";
        Character player = new Archer();
    }
```

The above code is where my problem arises.  I am creating an old-style text adventure game, and I have a class called `Character`.  It's sub-classes are the classes the player can choose from (wizard, warrior, rouge, etc.).  I know a class declared (again, not sure if I'm using the right word) in an if statement cannot be accessed outside the if statement, but if I don't declare it in the if statement, then the compiler won't know what subclass to use for that class.

Is there a way to make the classes accessible outside the if statements, or a way to declare the class outside the `if` statements, then change the subclass in the if statements?

Comment: PS rouge is a red color; rogue is a D&D class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare your variable *outside* the `if` statements, and assign to the variable *inside* the `if` statements. This is the same as your usage of the `playerClass` variable

Like this:

```
String playerClass = input.nextLine();
Character player = null;

if (playerClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Warrior")){
    playerClass = "warrior";
    player = new Warrior();
}
if (playerClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Rouge")){
    playerClass = "rouge";
    player = new Rouge();
}
```

This is assuming that `Warrior`, `Rouge`, ets are all sub-classes of `Character`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Instances of Objects

You do not create *copies* of objects you create `instances`. The semantic of `copy` is to create a completely separate but identical `instance` of an pre-existing `instance`. This is also called `clone` in Java incorrectly because of the semantics of the term `clone`.

#### Idiomatic Creation

```
final Character character; // assuming that all the instances subclass `Character`

if ("warrior".equalsIgnoresCase(playerClass)) { character= new Warrior(); }
else if ("cleric".equalsIgnoresCase(playerClass)) { character = new Cleric(); }
else if ( /* you get the idea */ ) { character= new Whatever();}
else() { throw new RuntimeException(playerClass + " is not a valid class"); }
```

Learning to use `final` correct is paramount to writing easy to maintain deterministic code.

It is important that all the `if/else if/else` are exclusionary so there are no edge cases that you miss. There is never a chance that `character` is `null` or not initialized correctly with this code.

The idiom `"SomeString".equalsIgnoreCase(variable);` of comparing the `String` literal to the variable insures that **you** never have to test for `null` and will not get a `NullPointerException` during the comparison because the `null` test is inside the method already.

This also avoids the use of `null` which is almost never appropriate and leads to lots of defensive programming and hard to maintain code. You either create a valid instance or you fail and you know exactly why it failed.

Having an instance of `Character` named `player` is confusing.

#### This should be a Factory Method Pattern

```
public Character characterFromClass(@Nonnull final String characterClass)
{
    if ("warrior".equalsIgnoreCase(characterClass)) { return new Warrior(); }
    else if ("cleric".equalsIgnoreCase(characterClass)) { return = new Cleric(); }
    else if ( /* you get the idea */ ) { return new Whatever();}
    else() { throw new RuntimeException(characterClass+ " is not a valid class"); }
}

final Character character = characterFromClass(input.nextLine());
```

[This is just one of many Creational Patterns available to you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)